# Does CreateIndex API support multicolumn indexes?

Tags: servicestack

Does the OrmLite CreateIndex API support multicolumn index?

It looks like it accepts just once column parameter:

```
db.CreateIndex<Table>(x => x.ColumnName);
```

Also is it possible to specifcy ascending/descending or nulls last?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not with the `CreateIndex` API but you can create composite indexes when creating a table using the `[CompositeIndex]` attribute, e.g:

```
[CompositeIndex(nameof(Username), nameof(Region))]
public class Profile
{
    [AutoIncrement]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public Region Region { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
}
```

You can add `ASC` or `DESC` against each column to specify ascending/descending, e.g:

```
[CompositeIndex("Username ASC", "Region DESC")]
public class Profile
{
    [AutoIncrement]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public Region Region { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes - using the [CompositeIndex](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.ormlite#create-tables-schemas) attribute.  Apply that at the class-level, and specify the column names for your index.